# Why do some constructors in this class use this(context) instead of super(context)?

Tags: java, android, oop

Why do two of the three constructors in this class use this(context) instead of super(context)?

The class is part of a larger project available at https://code.google.com/p/android-touchexample/source/browse/branches/cupcake/src/com/example/android/touchexample/TouchExampleView.java

```
package com.example.android.touchexample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class TouchExampleView extends View {

private Drawable mIcon;
private float mPosX;
private float mPosY;

private VersionedGestureDetector mDetector;
private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

public TouchExampleView(Context context) {
    this(context, null, 0);
}

public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TouchExampleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

    mDetector = VersionedGestureDetector.newInstance(context, new GestureCallback());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    mDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.save();
    canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
    canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
    mIcon.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}

private class GestureCallback implements VersionedGestureDetector.OnGestureListener {
    public void onDrag(float dx, float dy) {
        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;
        invalidate();
    }

    public void onScale(float scaleFactor) {
        mScaleFactor *= scaleFactor;

        // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
        mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

        invalidate();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe it's handy to know that when you are using a good IDE (Eclipse, or IntelliJ), ctrl+clicking on the 'this' or 'super' will bring you to the right constructor. It's helpful in finding out what code does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a constructor, `this()` does something different than `super()`.  Calling `this()` defers to an overloaded constructor in the same class.  Calling `super()` invokes a superclass constructor.

Here, the first two `TouchExampleView` constructors call `this` to defer to the third constructor by passing default value(s).  The third constructor calls `super` to invoke the superclass constructor (plus do a few other things).

The [Java Language Specification, Section 8.8.7.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7.1) describes these calls.

> Explicit constructor invocation statements can be divided into two kinds:
>
> Alternate constructor invocations begin with the keyword this
>   (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments). They are used to
>   invoke an alternate constructor of the same class.
>
> Superclass constructor invocations begin with either the keyword super
>   (possibly prefaced with explicit type arguments) or a Primary
>   expression. They are used to invoke a constructor of the direct
>   superclass.

Comment: That makes perfect sense now that you pointed it out.  Many thanks!